# signatures/types in functional programming (OCaml)

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, signature

I started learning functional programming (OCaml), but I don't understand one important topic about fp: signatures (I'm not sure if it's a proper name). When I type something and compile with ocaml, I get for example:

```
# let inc x = x + 1 ;;
val inc : int -> int = <fun>
```

This is trivial, but I don't know, why this:

```
let something f g a b = f a (g a b)
```

gives an output:

```
val something : (’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> (’a -> ’d -> ’b) -> ’a -> ’d -> ’c = <fun>
```

I suppose, that this topic is absolutely basics of fp for many of you, but I ask for help here, because I haven't found **anything** on the Internet about signatures in OCaml (there are some articles about signatures in Haskell, but not explanations).

If this topic somehow will survive, I post here several functions, which signatures made me confused:

```
# let nie f a b = f b a ;; (* flip *)
val nie : (’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> ’b -> ’a -> ’c = <fun>

# let i f g a b = f (g a b) b ;;
val i : (’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> (’d -> ’b -> ’a) -> ’d -> ’b -> ’c = <fun>


# let s x y z = x z (y z) ;;
val s : (’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> (’a -> ’b) -> ’a -> ’c = <fun>

# let callCC f k = f (fun c d -> k c) k ;;
val callCC : ((’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> (’a -> ’c) -> ’d) -> (’a -> ’c) -> ’d = <fun>
```

Thank you for help and explanation.

Comment: Terminology note (which could help your literature searches): “signatures” in Ocaml usually mean something else, namely an analog of types but for modules rather than basic expressions and values. What you're asking about is sometimes called “type signature” but often just “type”, or “type scheme” when there are variables.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a couple of concepts you need to understand to make sense of this type signature and I don't know which ones you already do, so I tried my best to explain every important concept:

## Currying

As you know, if you have the type `foo -> bar`, this describes a function taking an argument of type `foo` and returning a result of type `bar`. Since `->` is right associative, the type `foo -> bar -> baz` is the same as `foo -> (bar -> baz)` and thus describes a function taking an argument of type `foo` and returning a value of type `bar -> baz`, which means the return value is a function taking a value of type `bar` and returning a value of type `baz`.

Such a function can be called like `my_function my_foo my_bar`, which because function application is left-associative, is the same as `(my_function my_foo) my_bar`, i.e. it applies `my_function` to the argument `my_foo` and then applies the function that is returned as a result to the argument `my_bar`.

Because it can be called like this, a function of type `foo -> bar -> baz` is often called "a function taking two arguments" and I will do so in the rest of this answer.

## Type variables

If you define a function like `let f x = x`, it will have the type `'a -> 'a`. But `'a` isn't actually a type defined anywhere in the OCaml standard library, so what is it?

Any type that starts with a `'` is a so-called *type variable*. A type variable can stand for any possible type. So in the example above `f` can be called with an `int` or a `string` or a `list` or anything at all - it doesn't matter.

Furthermore if the same type variable appears in a type signature more than once, it will stand for the same type. So in the example above that means, that the return type of `f` is the same as the argument type. So if `f` is called with an `int`, it returns an `int`. If it is called with a `string`, it returns a `string` and so on.

So a function of type `'a -> 'b -> 'a` could take two arguments of any types (which might not be the same type for the first and second argument) and returns a value of the same type as the first argument, while a function of type `'a -> 'a -> 'a` would take two arguments of the same type.

One note about type inference: Unless you explicitly give a function a type signature, OCaml will always infer the most general type possible for you. So unless a function uses any operations that only work with a given type (like `+` for example), the inferred type will contain type variables.

## Now to explain the type...

```
val something : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'd -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'd -> 'c = <fun>
```

This type signature tells you that `something` is a function taking four arguments.

The type of the first argument is `'a -> 'b -> 'c`. I.e. a function taking two arguments of arbitrary and possibly different types and returning a value of an arbitrary type.

The type of the second argument is `'a -> 'd -> 'b`. This is again a function with two arguments. The important thing to note here is that the first argument of the function must have the same type as the first argument of the first function and the return value of the function must have the same type as the second argument of the first function.

The type of the third argument is `'a`, which is also the type of the first arguments of both functions.

Lastly, the type of the fourth argument is `'d`, which is the type of the second argument of the second function.

The return value will be of type `'c`, i.e. the return type of the first function.

Comment: Nice write-up.  I abandoned my version after seeing yours.  After currying and type variables, I would also throw type inferencing into the explanation.  As you know, the reason his first function said int -> int is because it was able to infer that from using the + operator.  His other functions don't provide that kind of information, so he ends up with type variables.

Comment: @xscott: Thanks. That's a good point. I've added a note to that effect as the last paragraph of the type variables section. I figured adding a whole section about type inference would be beyond the scope of this question. I think the important thing here is to understand what the types mean, not how ocaml comes up with them.

Comment: Wow, now I know much more! THANKS! But I have one question about this note: "The important thing to note here is that the first argument of the function must have the same type as the first argument of the first function and the return value of the function must have the same type as the second argument of the first function.". Why must? Why this should be doing this way, not other?

Comment: @lever7: Because the first argument of the first function is `'a` and the first argument of the second argument is also `'a`. If it would have been `'e` or `'f` or something else we haven't seen before, it could have been any type. But as I said, if the same type variable appears multiple times within the same signature, it must stand for the same type each time.

Comment: @lever: Or if your question was why that type follows from the definition: Both the function `f` and the function `g` take the same value (`a`) as their first argument. So they must take the same type as first argument. Further the result from calling `g` is used as the second argument to `f`. So the type of `f`'s second argument must be the same as the type returned by `g`.

Comment: Thank's, I think, I understand this now ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you're really interested in the subject (and have access to a university library), read Wadler's excellent (if somewhat dated) "Introduction to functional programming". It explains type signatures and type inference in a very nice and readable way.

Two further hints: Note that the -> arrow is right-associative, so you can bracket things from the right which sometimes helps to understand things, ie `a -> b -> c` is the same as `a -> (b -> c)`. This is connected to the second hint: Higher order functions. You can do things like

```
let add x y = x + y
let inc = add 1
```

so in FP, thinking of 'add' as a function that **has to** take two numerical parameters and returns a numerical value is **not generally** the right thing to do: It can also be a function that takes one numerical argument and returns a function with type num -> num.

Understanding this will help you understand type signatures, but you can do it without. Here, quick and easy:

```
# let s x y z = x z (y z) ;;
val s : (’a -> ’b -> ’c) -> (’a -> ’b) -> ’a -> ’c = <fun>
```

Look at the right hand side. `y` is given one argument, so it is of type `a -> b` where a is the type of `z`. `x` is given two arguments, the first one of which is `z`, so the type of the first argument has to be `a` as well. The type of `(y z)` , the second argument, is `b`, and hence the type of `x` is `(a -> b -> c)`. This allows you to deduce the type of `s` immediately.